# Powershell Select-object from cert store

Tags: powershell, certificate, powershell-2.0

Essentially I am trying to get the serial number of a certificate by using the subject so I can use it in a variable in CertUtil.

I am so close yet so far as you will see below can anybody help please?

```
cd cert:\localmachine\my

$serno = get-childitem | where { $_.subject -eq "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" } | format-list     -property * | select -property SerialNumber

$serno
```

this displays

```
SerialNumber        
------------
```

not the actual serial number

Does anybody have any clues??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use `format-list`, you already have all the properties. `format-list` will convert your nice `X509Certificate2` object into a set of format objects which isn't what you want at all. Also use `-expandproperty` on the `select`:

```
PS>get-childitem | where { $_.subject -eq "CN=localhost" } | select -expandproperty SerialNumber
6191F4A438FF77A24763E6D427749CD7
```

Or with Powershell 3 or later, use the shorthand notation:

```
PS>$serno = (get-childitem | where { $_.subject -eq "CN=localhost" }).SerialNumber
PS>$serno
6191F4A438FF77A24763E6D427749CD7
```

Comment: I put the following command like your top example:  
    $serno = get-childitem | where { $_.subject -eq "XXXXXXXX.local" } | select -expandproperty SerialNumber    and this returned nothing

Comment: Also I dont require it to be a certificate all i need to retrive is the serial number to pass on to certutil. Thanks for your time on this btw

Comment: Both of Duncan's examples worked for me.  I just substituted my serial number, I did not change "CN=localhost"

Comment: @choco_linux you do need it to be a certificate at the point where you try to access the `SerialNumber` property. Your `format-list` converts it all to text with headers and footers. If it's still not working for you please say what you get when you run just the first two parts of the pipeline, or just the first part. Maybe you haven't got the subject exactly right?

Comment: When I run get-childitem | where { $_.subject -eq "CN=XXXXXXXX.local" } I get back the particular certificate that I want but with only two columns Thumbprint and subject. The initial reason i used format-list was because when i did the -property * it brought back a considerable amount of information about the cert back.

Comment: It only displays 2 properties but the other properties are there. Using `select *` will show you all the properties; using `select -property SerialNumber` will give you an object with only a `SerialNumber` property. Using `select -expandproperty SerialNumber` will give you a string with the value of that property, which is what I think you want.

Comment: Thank you very much duncan it has worked. True gent! Thanks for your time mate :)